# In which xml namespace is filter-by-ip?

Tags: mule

I am new to mule, trying to use ip filtering. I have been reading 
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/34X/Mule+Filter+Processor

and trying to use the filter-by-ip-range in my application, but was unable to find after long googling the correct xml namespace.

If I do this:

there is exception at app deployment complaining about using "filters" namespace:
The prefix "filters" for element "filters:config" is not bound

That's fine because I haven't defined "filters" namespace it. But how to do it?

xmlns:filters "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/filters" was a thought, but that url does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the Anypoint Enterprise Security module that is *not* an open source project.

To install follow [these](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/34X/Installing+Anypoint+Enterprise+Security) instructions. Then you can download the [example application](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/download/attachments/95393327/anypoint-enterprise-security-example.zip?version=1&modificationDate=1380733571521) to find out namespaces and more.